# Insert new rows based on date in Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework

I have been handed over an application that uses entity framework. I'm not familiar with entity and I'm having an issue that I can't figure out. This application was made to migrate data from a database to a more relational database. After the initial migration, we have to run it again to insert additional rows that were not part of the original migration. (There is a 3 week gap). I know that I have to put a check in and I want to do this by one of the columns we uses named "DateChanged" but unfortunately I'm not sure how to do this in entity. This is my first effort and it just shows in red which is depressing. I have searched on the internet but have found no solutions.

```
 if (!newData.tVehicleLogs.Any(v => v.DateChanged.Value.ToShortDateString("6/27/2014")))//I'm not sure how to check the DateChanged here.
 {
      newData.tVehicleLogs.Add(deal);
      comment = new tVehicleComment
      {
         Comment = vehicle.Reason,
         DealID = deal.DealID,
         CurrentComment = false
       };
       newData.tVehicleComments.Add(comment);

       newData.SaveChanges();
       int cId = comment.CommentID;
       deal.CommentID = cId;
       }
  }
```

So as you can see I'm trying to check the date with the if statement, but I can't get the syntax correct... after trying everything I know to try .. which isn't much at this point.

I basically need to check if the DateChanged is from 6/27/2014 to today's date. If it's before then, then it has already been migrated over and doesn't need migrated over again. Where it says comment, if the row is new, then it inserts the old comment into the new comments table, then updates the tVehicleLogs table with the commentID. I'm just stuck on the date checking part. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

EDIT: This is the entire code for inserting the into tVehicleLogs..

```
if (MigrateLogs)
{
    List<VLog> vlog = oldData.VLogs.ToList();

    foreach (VLog vehicle in vlog)
    {

       tBank bank;
       tCustomer cust;
       tFIManager manag;
       tSalesPerson sales;
       tMake make;
       tModel model;
       tDealership dealership;
       tMakeDealership makedeal;
       tVehicleComment comment;
       tInternalLocation location;

       string dealershipName = getProperDealershipName(vehicle.Dealership, newData);

       bank = (newData.tBanks.Any(banks => banks.BankName == vehicle.BankName) ? newData.tBanks.Where(b => b.BankName == vehicle.BankName).FirstOrDefault() : newData.tBanks.Add(new tBank { BankName = vehicle.BankName }));

       cust = (newData.tCustomers.Any(customer => customer.CustomerNumber == vehicle.CustNumber) ? newData.tCustomers.Where(customer => customer.CustomerNumber == vehicle.CustNumber).FirstOrDefault() : newData.tCustomers.Add(new tCustomer { CustomerNumber = vehicle.CustNumber, CustomerName = vehicle.Buyer }));
                //cust = (newData.tCustomers.Any(customer => customer.CustomerNumber == vehicle.CustNumber && customer.CustomerName == vehicle.CustNumber) ? newData.tCustomers.Where(customer => customer.CustomerNumber == vehicle.CustNumber).FirstOrDefault() : newData.tCustomers.Add(new tCustomer { CustomerNumber = vehicle.CustNumber, CustomerName = vehicle.Buyer }));

       manag = (newData.tFIManagers.Any(manager => manager.FIName == vehicle.FIName) ? newData.tFIManagers.Where(manager => manager.FIName == vehicle.FIName).FirstOrDefault() : newData.tFIManagers.Add(new tFIManager { FIName = vehicle.FIName }));

       sales = (newData.tSalesPersons.Any(person => person.SalesPersonNumber == vehicle.SalesPerson) ? newData.tSalesPersons.Where(person => person.SalesPersonNumber == vehicle.SalesPerson).FirstOrDefault() : newData.tSalesPersons.Add(new tSalesPerson { SalesPersonNumber = vehicle.SalesPerson }));

       make = (newData.tMakes.Any(m => m.Make == vehicle.Make) ? newData.tMakes.Where(m => m.Make == vehicle.Make).FirstOrDefault() : newData.tMakes.Add(new tMake { Make = vehicle.Make }));

       model = (newData.tModels.Any(m => m.Model == vehicle.Model) ? newData.tModels.Where(m => m.Model == vehicle.Model).FirstOrDefault() : newData.tModels.Add(new tModel { Model = vehicle.Model, MakeID = make.MakeID }));

       dealership = (newData.tDealerships.Any(d => d.DealershipName == dealershipName) ? newData.tDealerships.Where(d => d.DealershipName == dealershipName).FirstOrDefault() : newData.tDealerships.Add(new tDealership { DealershipName = dealershipName }));

       makedeal = (newData.tMakeDealerships.Any(d => d.MakeID == make.MakeID && d.DealershipID == dealership.DealershipID) ? newData.tMakeDealerships.Where(d => d.MakeID == make.MakeID && d.DealershipID == dealership.DealershipID).FirstOrDefault() : newData.tMakeDealerships.Add(new tMakeDealership { DealershipID = dealership.DealershipID, MakeID = make.MakeID }));

       location = (newData.tInternalLocations.Any(l => l.LocationName == vehicle.Location) ? newData.tInternalLocations.Where(l => l.LocationName == vehicle.Location).FirstOrDefault() : newData.tInternalLocations.Add(new tInternalLocation { LocationName = vehicle.Location }));

       //log = (newData.tVehicleLogs.Any(l => l.DealNumber == vehicle.FIMAST &&) ? newData.tVehicleLogs.Where(l => l.DealNumber == vehicle.FIMAST).FirstOrDefault() : newData.tVehicleLogs.Add(new tVehicleLog {DealNumber = vehicle.FIMAST }));

       Int32 stat;
       int? status;

       if (Int32.TryParse(vehicle.Status, out stat))
           status = stat;
       else
           status = null;

       DateTime titled, bounced, dateReceived;
       bool trueTitled = DateTime.TryParse(vehicle.Titled, out titled);
       bool trueBounced = DateTime.TryParse(vehicle.Bounced, out bounced);
       bool trueReceived = DateTime.TryParse(vehicle.DateReceived, out dateReceived);

       int dealid = newData.tVehicleDeals.Where(v => v.DealNumber == vehicle.FIMAST).FirstOrDefault().DealID;

       tVehicleLog deal = new tVehicleLog
       {
          DealNumber = vehicle.FIMAST,
          StockNumber = vehicle.StockNumber,
          BankID = bank.BankID,
          CustomerID = cust.CustomerID,
          FIManagerID = manag.FIManagerID,
          SalesPersonID = sales.SalesPersonID,
          VINNumber = null,
          DealDate = vehicle.DealDate,
          NewUsed = vehicle.NewUsed,
          GrossProfit = vehicle.GrossProfit,
          AmtFinanced = vehicle.AmtFinanced,
          CloseDate = null,
          Category = vehicle.RetailLease,
          Status = status,
          DealershipID = dealership.DealershipID,
          NewDeal = false,
          Archived = false,
          InternalLocationID = location.InternalLocationID,
          ChangedBy = vehicle.ChangedBy,
          DateChanged = DateTime.Parse(vehicle.DateChanged),
          Titled = null,
          Bounced = null,
          MakeID = make.MakeID,
          ModelID = model.ModelID,
          DealID = dealid,
          CommentID = null
       };

       if (trueTitled)
           deal.Titled = titled;

       if (trueBounced)
           deal.Bounced = bounced;

       if (trueReceived)
           deal.DateReceived = dateReceived;

       DateTime targetDate = new DateTime(2014, 06, 27);

       //if(!newData.tVehicleLogs.Any(v => v.DateChanged >= targetDate))
       if(deal.DateChanged >= targetDate && !newData.tVehicleLogs.Any(v => v.DateChanged >= targetDate))
                {
           newData.tVehicleLogs.Add(deal);
           comment = new tVehicleComment
           {
               Comment = vehicle.Reason,
               DealID = deal.DealID,
               CurrentComment = false
            };
            newData.tVehicleComments.Add(comment);
            newData.SaveChanges();
            int cId = comment.CommentID;
            deal.CommentID = cId;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: You're using the term 'migration', but you're not talking about [EF Code first migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx), are you?

Comment: No, I don't think I am. Both Databases are already existing. We just 'migrated' the data from the old db to the new, more relational database.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to use linq here (providing you've pulled the object down). Just check the dates.

```
// pull down the object
var deal = newData.tVehicleLogs.Where(v => v.Id == SOMEID).FirstOrDefault();

DateTime targetDate = new DateTime(2014,06,27);
if (tVehicleLogs.DateChaned <= DateTime.Now 
    && tVehicleLogs.DateChaned >= targetDate) {
}
```

Alternatively, pull down all the objects that meet the date criteria and foreach over them.

```
List<YourObject> list = newData.tVehicleLogs.Where(v => v.DateChanged <= DateTime.Now
&& v.DateChanged >= targetDate).ToList();
foreach(var l in list) {
    // do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, but newData.tVehicleLogs doesn't have the column names so the newData.tVehicleLogs.DateChanged doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @Humpy are you saying the DateChanged field in the database does not have a corresponding property in the VehicleLogs class in your code?

Comment: So, DateChanged is not a property of tVehicleLogs?

@JeremyCook, beat me to it ;)

Comment: tVehicleLogs does have DataChanged. But the only way that I can see the date changed is if I do the Linq.. so newData.tVehicleLogs.Any(v => v.DateChanged ....))

Comment: Ohhh. So, newData is your EF Model. I'll update my example in a moment.

Comment: Ha, yeah. Sorry, like I say, I don't know EF well.. just a handed down project. I did however updated my question to show how the guy did this.

Comment: @fischgeek take a look at my edit to see if that makes more sense on how it's being done. Looks like we are using two models.. the oldData and the newData.

Comment: @fischgeek I have tried the 2nd option, but I'm getting Operation '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DateTime' and I have also had no luck searching for this as well in this context.

Comment: Can you confirm the datatype of the DateChanged property?

Comment: Looks like in the old database it's a varchar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57518/discussion-between-humpy-and-fischgeek).